# How do use regular expression keep the 0 start character when enter a decimal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this code to replace not numeric character,when the number is start with 0,like "000001111" or "0000000", 0 will be replace."000001111" change to "1111",and "0000000" change to "0".

But when I input a decimal,want this.

For example,I input "00012.340",keep "12.34",when I input "00.00" keep "0.0",when I input "000.0012" keep "0.0012".
how to fix my code's onkeyup?

My code:

```
<input id="text_target_value" maxlength="11" class="text-right number" type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d]+|^0+(?!$)/g, '')" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: [`parseFloat()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to trim *leading* zeros, leave one leading zero if followed by a decimal point or the end of the string, *and* you want to trim trailing zeros after the decimal point.

You can match non-digit, non-period characters with:

```
[^\d.]
```

and you can match the undesirable leading zeros with

```
^0+(?=0(\.|$)|\d)
```

In other words, match leading zeros, followed by `0.`, or by `0` and the end of the string, or by some other digit.

The above two patterns can be replaced with the empty string.

Then, to trim the *trailing* zeros, you'll have to *capture* the decimal point and the decimal digits in a group, then match the trailing zeros, and replace with the first captured group:

```js
document.querySelector('#text_target_value').onkeyup = function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^\d.]+|^0+(?=0(\.|$)|\d)/g, '')
    // Still need to trim trailing zeros after decimal point:
    .replace(/(\.\d*[1-9])0+$/, '$1');
}
```

```html
<input id="text_target_value" maxlength="11" class="text-right number" type="text">
```

Might be clearer to replace the non-digits and non-periods first, and to keep the regex for the leading zeros separate:

```
this.value = this.value
  // Replace anything that isn't a digit or a period:
  .replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')
  // Replace undesirable leading zeros:
  .replace(/^0+(?=0(\.|$)|\d)/g, '')
  // Still need to trim trailing zeros after decimal point:
  .replace(/(\.\d*[1-9])0+$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple calls to `replace()` method. You could do it in a single step:

```
value.replace(/^0*(?!\.)|(0)0*$/g, '$1');
```

Regex:

```
^0*(?!\.)|(0)0*$
```

This will match all leading `0`s that don't immediately follow a decimal point and all trailing `0`s. Then tries to replace whole match with `$1` which has a value when second side of alternation is satisfied.